# Why does this usage of jQuery.countdown show the wrong date difference?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have put together a countdown with the help of the **[jQuery.countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)**. The goal is to count the from the current date until this year's Christmas.

The result, as you can see, is very much off-target. Where is my mistake?

```js
function doCountDown(countDownContainer, endDate) {
  $(countDownContainer).countdown(endDate, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('<ul class="list-unstyled clock">' +
      '<li class="days"><span>%-d</span><span>days</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="hrs"><span>%H</span><span>hours</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="mins"><span>%M</span><span>minutes</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="seconds"><span>%S</span><span>seconds</span></li></ul>'));
  });
}

doCountDown('#count_down', '2021/12/25');
```

```css
.clock {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.clock li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #efefef;
  background: #343434;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.clock li span {
  line-height: 1;
}

.clock li span:last-child {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="conrainer">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4 my-3">Party starts in...</h1>
    <div id="count_down"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html#formatter) `%-d` in the formatter takes in to account the number of weeks remaining too. I.e. 6 weeks and 1 day would be just '1 day' shown in `%-d`.

To correct this use `%-D` which is the *total* number of days until the end date:

```js
function doCountDown(countDownContainer, endDate) {
  $(countDownContainer).countdown(endDate, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('<ul class="list-unstyled clock">' +
      '<li class="days"><span>%-D</span><span>days</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="hrs"><span>%H</span><span>hours</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="mins"><span>%M</span><span>minutes</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="seconds"><span>%S</span><span>seconds</span></li></ul>'));
  });
}


doCountDown('#count_down', '2021-12-25');
```

```css
.clock {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.clock li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #efefef;
  background: #343434;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.clock li span {
  line-height: 1;
}

.clock li span:last-child {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="conrainer">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4 my-3">Party starts in...</h1>
    <div id="count_down"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great job! However, isn't the counter one hour behind? It shows 1 hour more to me.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's doing the same to me, although my local time is UTC+1, so I would guess the plugin is working in UTC perhaps...?

Comment: Have a look at **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69525188/4512005)** attempt to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If I could make a guess based on the example in the plugin I think you're missing the amount of weeks. Something like this?

```
  '<li class="weeks"><span>%-w</span><span>weeks</span></li> '
```