# How can I do a timezone adjustment while using The Final Countdown plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have put together a countdown with the help of the **[jQuery.countdown plugin](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)**. The goal is to count the from the current date until this year's Christmas.

#### The problem

Due to the fact that the plugin uses **UTC** as a reference, I get a 1 hour time gap.

#### How I tried to fix this problem

The solution I tried involves the use of moment.js:

```js
function doCountDown(countDownContainer, endDate) {
  $(countDownContainer).countdown(endDate, function(event) {
    $(this).html(event.strftime('<ul class="list-unstyled clock">' +
      '<li class="days"><span>%-D</span><span>days</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="hrs"><span>%H</span><span>hours</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="mins"><span>%M</span><span>minutes</span></li> ' +
      '<li class="seconds"><span>%S</span><span>seconds</span></li></ul>'));
  });
}

let deadLine = moment.tz('2021-12-25 00:00:00', 'Europe/Bucharest');
doCountDown('#count_down', deadLine.toDate());
```

```css
.clock {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.clock li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 58px;
  height: 58px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #efefef;
  background: #4caf50;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.clock li span {
  line-height: 1;
}

.clock li span:last-child {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.4.0/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/2.2.0/dist/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="conrainer">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="h4 my-3">Party starts in...</h1>
    <div id="count_down"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For a reason I was unable to spot, this **does not work**. It is **1 hour behind the computer**.

How can I reliably do a timezone adjustment?

Comment: Your code seems to work. It matches this exactly: https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/christmas

Comment: @BenAlan But it does not match my computer's time. To match the computer, it should show 1 hour less.

Comment: Perhaps there is an offset because of DST? Either your computer or moment.js is not adding the offset. The good news is that, by November, the problem will fix itself.

Comment: @BenAlan What's DST?

Comment: Daylight Savings Time. Does this help? https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Comment: @BenAlan How do I (automatically) adjust for Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: Adding the line: deadLine.utc(); should give you the time without DST. See if that matches your computer. The way you have it now, I believe it IS adjusting for DST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.

My theory is your computer is not adding daylight savings time, but moment.js is.

```
let deadLine = moment.tz('2021-12-25 00:00:00', 'Europe/Bucharest');
deadLine.utc(); //add this to turn off dst
doCountDown('#count_down', deadLine.toDate());
```

Comment: I tried it. Apparently, it does not work. Have you tested it?